# Shell Script getting terminated in the middle when unable to make DB connection

Tags: postgresql, shell, enterprisedb

I have a function block as below which is getting called from somewhere. The call is happening fine but when it's executing any of the below psql check commands eg:

```
local db_availability_check_88=`psql -h 10.95.187.88 -p 5444 -c "\pset tuples_only" -c "select pg_is_in_recovery;"|grep -v "Tuples"`
```

The script terminates immediately if the script is unable to communicate to the database via the above psql command. I want thee script to continue its execution. If the connectivity fails it should continue with the next statements.

```
check_db_status_function () {
    echo "entered function block db_status"
    local db_availability_check_67=`psql -h 10.95.167.87 -p 5444 -c "\pset tuples_only" -c "select pg_is_in_recovery;"|grep -v "Tuples"`
    local db_availability_check_68=`psql -h 10.95.167.88 -p 5444 -c "\pset tuples_only" -c "select pg_is_in_recovery;"|grep -v "Tuples"`
    local db_availability_check_69=`psql -h 10.95.167.89 -p 5444 -c "\pset tuples_only" -c "select pg_is_in_recovery;"|grep -v "Tuples"`

      if [[ ( $a1 = "down" ) && ( $a3 != "primary" ) && ( $db_availability_check_67 = 't' ) ]];
      then
      echo "pgPool services are down on the node:$a2"
      echo "Promoting..."
      /u01/edb/pgpool3.6/bin/pcp_attach_node -w -U pcpuser -h localhost -p 9898 $a0
      fi
```

The script o/p is as :

```
Nested block 1
check_db_stat
entered function block db_status
psql.bin: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "10.95.167.88" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5444?
```

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: Please let me know if anyone can help on this.

Comment: Not clear to me why this would be happening. To go back to basics, what happens when you run just the bare command `psql -h 10.95.187.88 -p 5444 -c "\pset tuples_only" -c "select pg_is_in_recovery;" ; echo $?` on a failing node?

Comment: This will give the same output as mentioned above..

Comment: yes, and what is printed from the `echo $?` portion? Also, can you look in the underlying system logs and see if there are any errors attributable to this?

Comment: did you do `set -e` in your shell script when you shouldn't have?

Comment: It might actually be more helpful to see the entire script.  I tried running your code, and it continues instead of stopping at the first failure